# add user to turnkeylinux.org, Trac instance

Tags: trac, turnkeylinux.org

I'm trying to get up and running on Trac quickly for a pending migration. Could someone tell me how to add new users to Trac. As I understand it trac authenticates against apache, which uses a password file. I know how to use htpasswd but I don't know where the password file is. Am I going down the wrong road here?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your Apache configuration (like mod_python.conf) you'll have a line that specifies where the authentication file is:

```
AuthUserFile /var/lib/trac/your_auth_file
```

While you're in looking at that file, look for the base Trac directory.  It may be specified as:

```
PythonOption TracEnv /var/lib/trac/yourProject
```

Once you've used `htpasswd` to add them to that file, you'll want to add them to Trac, so you'll need to run `trac-admin`:

```
trac-admin /var/lib/trac/yourProject
```

You can then issue a `help` command to learn how to add users to trac, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was use htpasswd in the folder where my track site was. And then I was able to use the admin tool in track to give that user permission in track.

Comment: Where was the Trac site located at?